# Equal lists returning false - Java

Tags: java

I have two lists, with exactly the same values, but when I use the equal() method it returns false... Can someone help me... Here is my code.

```
@Test
public void testPolygonConstructor(){
    try {
        Triangle t = new Triangle("Triangle 3 4 9 4 3 8");
        Point a1 = new Point(3,4);
        Point a2 = new Point(9,4);
        Point a3 = new Point(3,8);
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(a1,a2,a3));
        System.out.println(t.coordenadas);
        System.out.println(list);
        System.out.println(t.coordenadas.equals(list));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

My output is:

> [3 4, 9 4, 3 8]
>   [3 4, 9 4, 3 8]
>   false

EDIT: TRIANGLE CLASS

```
public class Triangle extends Polygon {
    public Triangle(String s) throws Exception {
        super(s);
        if (!isValid()) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        if (isAllEqual() || coordenadas.size() != 3) {
            return false;
        }
        double lado1 = coordenadas.get(0).dist(coordenadas.get(1));
        double lado2 = coordenadas.get(0).dist(coordenadas.get(2));
        double lado3 = coordenadas.get(1).dist(coordenadas.get(2));
        if (lado1 + lado2 > lado3 && lado1 + lado3 > lado2 && lado2 + lado3 > lado1) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

And my polygon class (which is superclass of triangle is = )

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class Polygon {
    protected List<Point> coordenadas = new ArrayList<Point>();

    public Polygon(String s) throws Exception {
        coordenadas = readPoints(s);
        if (coordenadas.isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    private List<Point> readPoints(String s) {

        s = s.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", " ");
        s.trim().split(" ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            list.add(scanner.nextInt());
        }
        scanner.close();
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            Point k = new Point(list.get(i), list.get(i + 1));
            coordenadas.add(j, k);
            j++;
        }
        return coordenadas;

    }

    public Point centroid() {
        double x = 0;
        double y = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < coordenadas.size(); i++) {
            x += coordenadas.get(i).getX();
            y += coordenadas.get(i).getY();
        }

        x = x / coordenadas.size();
        y = y / coordenadas.size();
        return new Point((int) x, (int) y);

    }

    public double perimeter() {
        double distance = 0;
        int len = coordenadas.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            distance += coordenadas.get(i).dist(coordenadas.get((i + 1) % len));
        }
        return distance;
    }

    public boolean isAllEqual() {
        Point first = coordenadas.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < coordenadas.size(); i++) {
            if (!coordenadas.get(i).Equals(first))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public abstract boolean isValid();                          

}
```

I guess the problem might be that "coordenadas" is protected???

EDIT2 : HERE IS THE POINT CLASS SORRY GUYS!!

```
public class Point {

    private double x = 0, y = 0;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    public boolean Equals(Point p) {
        return this.x == p.getX() && this.y == p.getY();
    }

    public double dist(Point p) {
        double dx = getX() - p.getX();
        double dy = getY() - p.getY();
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return ((int) getX() + " " + (int) getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `t.coordenadas`?

Comment: needs code for Triangle and Point classes, but chances are you have not implemented equals/hashCode for Point class.

Comment: In my class Polygon

protected List<Point> coordenadas = new ArrayList<Point>();

Comment: Clarify your question by add more information about what is Triangle and Point classes

Comment: @PedroMartins Please don't put code in comments on your question.  Instead, [edit] your question to add any additional information that would help people answer it.

Comment: Edit completed. polygon and triangle class

Comment: What about the Point class?

Comment: Sorry, point class is there now!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Point` class does not override `equals` method from `Object`.

you can change the method `Equals` to `equals`

or add this method to `Point` class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Point) {
        Point pt = (Point) obj;
        return (x == pt.x) && (y == pt.y);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer with solve of your problem.

Answer (score -1):

Is the Triangle class something you created?  You'll need to overload the equals(Object o) method with your own implementation.  Otherwise the default equals method will be used.  Since these are two different objects, the result will be false.

This is just a start

```
 public boolean equals(List input) {

       return compare(point1, input) && compare(point2, input) && compare(point3, input);

    }
```

Comment: Why are you comparing a `Point` to a `List`?

Comment: just a start...  maybe the points are in a different order.  each point should be checked.  compare() was bad naming.